# ASP NET countdown timer with from Label1.Text

Tags: asp.net

There is possible to start countdown timer with date from any control like Label.Text or TextBox.Text?
I found only with a specific date like 2018-10-22 03:42:37 but i need that date from control.

Comment: do you mean to show date with time countdown in label or textbox?

Comment: Hi @Leszcz, if you have enough right to edit your question and answer, here you merge your answers and delete extra. Only one answer to add, so it will help to others and found directly their answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply add a timer control and the value of timer you will show to any label

```
 <asp:timer id="Timer1" runat="server" interval="1000" ontick="Timer1_Tick" xmlns:asp="#unknown"></asp:timer>
<asp:lable id="Lable1" runat="server" xmlns:asp="#unknown" />
```

Just see the example in this links
[Countdown timer on ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109064/countdown-timer-on-asp-net-page)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5yyXtIvyYxc

or you can use javascript if you only show

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function countdown() 
    {
        seconds = document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML;
        if (seconds > 0) 
        {
            document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML = seconds - 1;
            setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
        }
    }

    setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);

</script>
```

[Countdown timer on ASP.NET page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109064/countdown-timer-on-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 controls 1 is with DataBind from SQL(When user click is insert DateAdd +12 hour) date and second shold show cutdown 
I was try this one

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

But this way does not read date from control.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution
Heres my. I dont remeber who made tish but credits for him.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost; database=DB_TS; trusted_connection=true;");
            con.Open();

            string queryString = @"Select * from Vote";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = dr["Data2"].ToString();

            }

            dr.Close();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();                

        }


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt2.ToString());
        Label1.Text = CalculateTimeDifference(startDate, endDate);


    }

    public string CalculateTimeDifference(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        int days = 0; int hours = 0; int mins = 0; int secs = 0;
        string final = string.Empty;
        if (endDate > startDate)
        {
            days = (endDate - startDate).Days;
            hours = (endDate - startDate).Hours;
            mins = (endDate - startDate).Minutes;
            secs = (endDate - startDate).Seconds;
            final = string.Format("{0} days {1} hours {2} mins {3} secs", days, hours, mins, secs);
        }
        return final;
    }
```